# Unfortunately has Stopped in Android

Tags: android

Unfortunately appname has stopped, while I am using main activity for both androidmanifest.xml file and for the Java file, so there is no chance of using different activities, but still i am getting this message,like:

`Unfortunately LunchList has Stopped`.

I am getting this when I am making simple Android app with SQLite database, RSS Reader and much more, but the thing is my codes are working fine because not showing me an error of coding and I am able to run and debug my apps. I am also getting problem with option menus like sometimes menus are not coming, sometimes they are coming but not responding.

Comment: Can you Please Show us your Exact Error and can display your piece of Code in which you are getting error?

Comment: once u restart ur eclipse,nd emulator then it worksss

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Answer (score 1):

> but the thing is my codes are working fine because not showing me an error of coding

You mean it's compiling? That's not the same as *working*. Clearly your code *isn't* working, otherwise it wouldn't be crashing like this.

You should look in your application's log file (e.g. with [logcat](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html)). I'm confident it will show you an exception, with a stack trace. That should give you a good idea of what's going wrong, and where it's going wrong. If you find out what's going wrong but don't understand *why* it's going wrong, that's a reasonable Stack Overflow question in itself, but the first thing is to get that initial diagnostic information.

Note that if you run your app in the debugger, I'd expect that if this error occurs, the debugger should stop to show you where the problem is. (I've never built an Android app, so I can't swear that's the case, but it's a reasonable expectation.)

Answer (score 0):

When you encounter a FC ( Force Close ), You should monitor your application. In Eclipse open the DDMS view and monitor the application with logcat. and see what causes the problem!